# how to access and use query string of URL that has been rewritten

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am working on a script which heavily relies on reading variables from the URL to determine what to do and what to show.
In order to make it more SEO friendly I have added the following URL rewriting to an .htaccess file in the root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=(?!admin)(?!superadmin)((?![^&]*?edit)[^\s&]+) [NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This completely removes the query string from the browser's address bar, however a lot in the script does not work anymore because the variables $_GET['var'] are now empty...

is there a way I can still read the contents of the variables that are being sent in the URLs?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know mod rewrite well but there is redirect 301, isn't there? You can get URL by `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, then use `parse_url` and then finally get all values by `parse_str`

Comment: @estshy $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is a rewritten URL and therefore it doesn't contain the query string

Answer (score 1):

You're using rewriting backwards. The user should go to `page/var1val/var2val/` and you rewrite (on backend) to `page.php?var1=var1val&var2=var2val`. If you're starting with the second url and rewriting to the first, its wrong.

That is, in other words: The user should go to a pretty url, and in the backend you translate that to an oldschool url with the `?` and the parameter names.

If the user is going with an oldschool url with `?` and the parameter names in it and you're just stripping them off, there's no way that could ever work right.

Comment: the reason I have it this way is because I want domain.com/Home to take the user to domain.com/index.php?p=Home however I want the URL to still show domain.com/Home and not the old school url. When the user clicks on a link in the homepage that goes to domain.com/index.php?p=Bio then the URL will show domain.com/index.php?p=Bio while I want it to show domain.com/Bio - that is why I had it this way, do you know what I mean? Given all of that, do you still thing it's wrong?

Comment: If you stop linking to the oldschool urls the only users who will go to them are those using old bookmarks (or those tinkering), and eventually as they navigate the site they'll be broken out of that due to you linking to the new style urls, right? i.e. because you'll link directly to domain.com/Bio  not domain.com/index.php?p=Bio

Comment: as I explain in my original post the structure of the website relies heavily on URL query strings so if by "linking directly" to the new school url you mean linking from other websites, then yes, but if you mean browsing between the pages of the website itself, the links will have to be old school to work, you know what I mean? if I am misunderstanding you (which is quite possible as I am very new to url rewriting) would you mind changing my htacess rules to reflect what you mean so I can see it in action? I would greatly appreciate that. Thanks

Comment: "if you mean browsing between the pages of the website itself, the links will have to be old school to work" No, that's the whole point of rewriting. The pretty url comes in, and on the backend your rewrite to the oldschool links so it will work but the user never sees the oldschool links.

Comment: sorry but I am confused... I want the user not to see the oldschool links but I can't rewrite my entire script so that the links between pages point to the newschool links... in other words a link to the homepage on the page domain.com/index.php?p=Bio will still point to domain.com/index.php?p=Home except the user will think he is on domain.com/Bio and when the user clicks a link to the homepage he will think he is on domain.com/Home - isn't that the point?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?(.*)p=(?!admin)(?!superadmin)((?![^&]*?edit)[^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?(.*)p=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\   ]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2?%1%3 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thank you so much for your willingness to help... unfortunately this seems to put the website in some sort of loop or something weird... nothing shows up... the error log shows a PHP Warning about a getimagesize function that failed to open stream (HTTP request failed!)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the query string will be in `$_GET['p']`.  Try:

```
parse_str($_GET['p'], $_GET);
```

Or maybe:

```
parse_str(urldecode($_GET['p']), $_GET);
```

This will overwrite the current `$_GET`.  Use another var if needed.

Comment: $_GET['p'] is empty because the user comes from a rewritten URL